# jquery, if class in html parent class get active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tryed, but I did not get result.
I just cerate my idea here

Html

```
<html>
  <div>
    <div class="spinner">
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Jquery

```
if (".spinner"){
this.parent.addClass()
}
else {
this.parent. removeClass() }
```

What i want, if spinner class added inside the html code, the spinner parent class get add some css styling. If spinner class is removed from html, the spinner parent class have get out from that what we have added. How may i do this?

Thanks for you advise.

Comment: How you are removing spinner class? where you removing this at the same location remove its parent class first.

Comment: Where in your html is your JavaScript? Maybe you're executing the javascript before your DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues.

Firstly, change your div to have the **class** of spinner, like so:

```
<div class="spinner">
```

Then, change your jQuery from referencing `this` (the JavaScript object) to `$(this)` (the jQuery object), like so:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("spinner")){
    $(this).addClass("spinner"));
}
else {
    $(this).removeClass("spinner"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div>
<div class="spinner">
</div>
```

Function:

```
function updateSpinnerParent(){
    var ref = $(".spinner"),
    cls = "hello";

    if(ref.length > 0){
      // element(s) with class 'spinner' is present
      ref.parent().addClass(cls);
    }else{
      // element(s) with class 'spinner' is not present
      ref.parent().removeClass(cls);
    }
}
```

Call the function whenever you want to update the parent element as such:

```
updateSpinnerParent();
```

Comment: `if(ref.length > 0)` here what does the meaning of this line?

Comment: A very crude sanity check - to see if our jQuery object has any matched elements. Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/length/

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var spDiv = $(".spinner");
if (spDiv){
    spDiv.parent().addClass("spinner");
}else {
    spDiv.parent().removeClass("spinner"); 
}
```

Greetings.